# Serial Port on Shutdown and power on the PC not working for the first time in windows 7

Tags: windows, serial-port

In windows 7, I am creating a serial port on COM1 programmatically in win32. I am connecting a serial device to this port. When I shutdown the terminal and power on again, for the first time when I am writing to the port, I am not able to get any response from the device. But from second time on wards, I am able to get the response. What might be the reason that the Write to serial port fails for the first time?

Comment: Verify that you initialize DTR, RTS hardware flow control lines when you opening the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible when you first write to the port, that the connection to the port gets configured. As if there was a method which checks if the port is reachable or if there is an actual connection to it.